# Dropzone.js firefox compatibility

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dropzone.js

I'm experiencing a strange issue with dropzone.js. Before downloading and testing the plugin myself I checked if it's on site demo works with chrome, firefox and IE, the plugin worked perfectly on all three browsers. After downloading the plugin I noticed that it works in chrome and IE but not in firefox, does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles by, the problem was leaving the action field empty. For some reason it disrupted the plugin in Firefox. Anyway, I just added a value action="bla.html" and now it works.

Comment: You're the best! That seems to be what the issue is.

Unfortunately, fixing that is much more difficult for me because I'm writing an angular app and the form my input is inside is nested in another form. This means it can't be a "real" form and has to be a div or ng-form, so... hrmm...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with DropZone in Firefox where any dropped files would automatically be opened. I fixed it by disabling the default behavior at the window level.

```
window.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```